# How to compile sklearn file *.pyx

Tags: scikit-learn, pyx

When I want to compile the file in scikit-learn-master\sklearn\ensemble_gradient_boosting.pyx, I use the command "python setup.py build" to compile the _gradient_boosting.pyx, but it have some error follow. So I want to konw how to compile the pyx file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ5S8.png)

Comment: Please provide a lot more details.  What OS?  What C compiler?  What version of scikit-learn?  What version of Cython?  Have you tried "python setup.py build_ext"?  This information will allow others to try to duplicate the problem?

Comment: OS: win7. vs2015 compiler. scikit-learn 0.18. I have tired python setup.py build_ext

Comment: What about Cython?

Comment: I use anaconda3-4.3.0.1, I do not the version of Cython

Comment: Go to a command prompt and type "conda list cython".

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?